# Ruby Array to Histogram. How to group numbers by range?

Tags: ruby

I need to group the array values into a range-based histogram in ruby...

```
values = [ 139, 145, 149, 151, 152, 153, 163, 166, 169 ]
```

for example:

```
141 - 145 = 2
146 - 150 = 1
151 - 155 = 3
```

...

Is there a simple  way to use `group_by`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prepare a histogram one normally specifies the smallest value of the first range, the range size and the number of ranges. Some pre-processing of the data may be necessary to determine those values. For example, given

```
values = [139, 145, 149, 151, 152, 153, 164, 166, 169]
group_size = 5
```

we might compute the smallest value of the first group and the number of groups as follows:

```
smallest, largest = values.minmax
  #=> [139, 169] 
start = group_size*(smallest/group_size)
  #=> 135 
nbr_groups = ((largest-start+1)/group_size.to_f).ceil
  #=> 7
```

We can now construct an array we can use to create the histogram.

```
def group_values(values, start, nbr_groups, group_size)
  groups = Array.new(nbr_groups) do |i|
    f = start + i * group_size
    { nbr: 0, range: f..f+group_size-1 }
  end    
  values.each_with_object(groups) { |v,arr|
    arr[(v-start)/group_size][:nbr] += 1 }
end
```

Let's try it (for the values of `start` and `nbr_groups` computed above).

```
freq = group_values(values, start, nbr_groups, group_size)
  #=> group_values(values, 135, 7, 5)
  #=> [{:nbr=>1, :range=>135..139},
  #    {:nbr=>0, :range=>140..144},
  #    {:nbr=>2, :range=>145..149},
  #    {:nbr=>3, :range=>150..154},
  #    {:nbr=>0, :range=>155..159},
  #    {:nbr=>1, :range=>160..164},
  #    {:nbr=>2, :range=>165..169}]
```

Note that

- the value of `:range` for each element of the resulting array is provided for labeling the horizontal axis of the histogram.
- I initialized the array `groups` so that groups containing no elements of `values` (for values `140-144` and `155-159`) would be included in the array returned. Had I constructed that array on the fly it would not have contained the hashes for those two groups.
- to establish the range of frequencies for the vertical axis of the histogram we might compute the following.

```
freq.map { |h| h[:nbr] }.minmax
  #=> [0, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're dealing with a simple definition for each range, then yes:

```
values.group_by do |v|
  (v-1) / 5
end.values
# => [[139], [145, 149], [151, 152, 153], [163], [166, 169]]
```

Normally `group_by` includes the grouping element, too, but this can be ignored as in this case it's not useful.

You can transform this into the form you're looking for with this using Ranges:

```
values.group_by do |v|
  (v-1) / 5
end.map do |v, a|
  [ (v*5+1..v*5+5), a.length ]
end.to_h
# => {136..140=>1, 141..145=>1, 146..150=>1, 151..155=>3, 161..165=>1, 166..170=>2}
```